# vue.js 2.0 alpha error on start

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, vue.js

when i run on my local pc vuejs 2.0 i have some error:

[instruction on start vude.js 2.0 alpha](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/tree/next)

- **npm install**
- **npm run build**

```
$ NODE_ENV=production node build/build.js
[Error: Could not load C:\OpenServer\domains\vue\src\core/index (imported by C:/OpenServer/doma
ins/vue/src/entries/web-runtime.js): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\OpenServer\dom
ains\vue\src\core\index']
```

what does that mean?

my cfg:

1. windows 10 pro x64
2. npm - **v3.8.3**
3. node - **v5.10.1**

Comment: I would make an issue on Github as this alpha is a brand new product that most of us haven't looked at yet